# Ansible: How to get hostname without domain name?

Tags: ansible

How to get value from `/etc/hostname` ignoring domain name. For example, `/etc/hostname` says `"client.test.dom"` and I need to get `"client"`.

I have tried `"{{ ansible_nodename | replace('.rail.dom','') }}"` but I get syntax problem and can't figure out how to solve it.

Comment: Regarding "_I get syntax problem and can't figure out how to solve it._" can you describe that in more detail and provide more information?

Answer (score 4):

It is assumed that you have a proper and valid inventory defined. Then, according [Information about Ansible: magic variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_vars_facts.html#information-about-ansible-magic-variables)

> *You can use the magic variable `inventory_hostname`, the name of the host as configured in your inventory, as an alternative to `ansible_hostname` when fact-gathering is disabled. If you have a long FQDN, you can use `inventory_hostname_short`, which contains the part up to the first period, without the rest of the domain.*

If [facts are gathered](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_vars_facts.html) you can use additionally `ansible_hostname` or `ansible_facts['nodename']`.

A minimal example playbook

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: true

  tasks:

  - name: Show hostname
    debug:
      msg: "Host: {{ ansible_hostname }} FQDN: {{ ansible_nodename }}"
```

will result into an output of

```yaml
TASK [Show hostname] *********************
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg: 'Host: test FQDN: test.example.com'
```

---

You may then have a look into the following examples

```yaml
  - name: Split nodename
    debug:
      msg: "{{ ansible_nodename.split('.')[0] }}"

  - name: Split nodename
    debug:
      msg: "{{ ansible_nodename | split('.') | first }}"
```

resulting both into an output of

```yaml
TASK [Split nodename] ******
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg: test
```

**Further Documentation**

- [`split` filter – split a string into a list](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/collections/ansible/builtin/split_filter.html)

**Similar Q&A**

- [Ansible string split](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69433646/6771046)
- [How to split value in Ansible with delimiter?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55194553/6771046)
- [What's the difference between `inventory_hostname` and `ansible_hostname`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45908067/)